# Reflexive graph, meaning of the reflection

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, universal-algebra

[Here](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/papers/spegra.pdf) on the page 1 there is a definition of **reflexive graph**. I need an intuition how it works the morphism $e:X_0\to X_1.$ What is it and to what edge in $X_1$ it sends a vertex from $X_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sends a vertex $v$ to an looped edge $e \circ v$ that is from $v$ to $v$, where $\circ$ is composition of functions. The word "reflexive" in the graph means such edges exist.
For details on reflexive graphs, see "Lawvere, Rosebrugh: Sets for mathematics".

Comment: It's not $e\circ v$ but rather $e(v)$ here, if $e$ is a function and $v\in X_0$.